# How do I change the Heroes array, to the res array? I am using the react useState hook. This has worked on previous projects but not here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [Heroes, setHeroes] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        API.findFavorites().then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            setHeroes([...Heroes, res]);
            console.log(Heroes)
        })
    }, []);
```

I am trying to set the state of Heroes to the res so I can use it in a useEffect. But it does not set, I have tried a lot of different solutions online but none are working!
the API.findFavorites returns a response that looks like [{...}, {...}].
When I console.log(Heroes) it logs as [], instead of [{...}, {...}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State updates may be asynchronous, so there is no guarantee that you can accces it immediately after setting it.

[Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

This is also true for useState hooks.
Setting state doesn’t update the state right away. Rather, it enqueues the update operation.

So you need to have a second useEffect with Heroes dependency.

```
  const [Heroes, setHeroes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    API.findFavorites().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      setHeroes([...Heroes, res]);   
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Heroes);
  }, [Heroes]);
```

[Sample codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hamilton-0vn9w)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know you could have 2 useEffects on a page. Very helpful!

Comment: @ChaseL you are welcome, please don’t forget to mark as answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers